# What is the equivalent of "FOR XML AUTO" in MySQL? (for having an XML string that represents a row)

Tags: mysql, xml, t-sql

In SQL Server I frequently use "FOR XML AUTO", which allows something like "SELECT id FROM car FOR XML AUTO" to return "<car><id>1</id></car><car><id>2</id></car>". Is there a way to do this in MySQL? 

What I want is to be able to store this XML in another table so I can have complete log of changes made in the database. The history table will be populated by triggers, and each row will be a denormalized representation of the row that changed; storing XML seems like a great way to change the definition of a table and not worry about messing up the log history. So what I need is a simple and straightforward way to have an string that can be inserted as a data value, and this is string must be the XML description of the row.

Thank you very much!
Regards,

Pedro

Comment: a complete log of changes in the db? in XML? sounds like it will become massive pretty quickly. Are you sure this is the best way to accomplish what you need?

Comment: The article http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041807-1.shtml seems pretty good, and this way can be good for this particular project. It can become massive pretty quickly, but it can be dumped often. History will be only used exceptionally, but it is important for some tables. There might be better ways, specially if this is not as straightforward as I was excepting. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_xql/index.php for the lib_mysqludf_xql library from the MySQL UDF Repository.

The library provides a set of functions that generate XML output similar to SQL/XML as seen in Oracle/SQL Server. There are download/build/install instructions on the page along with a description of the library and the various functions it provides.

These should be sufficient to be used from within a trigger as you were planning.

-Dipin

Comment: Great! I still have to install and check this solution, but it seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

See http://eriksdiary.blogspot.com/2007/07/xml-output-from-mysql.html

for a way to do this in mysql. It's a workaround... and not terribly straightforward but afaik mysql doesn't have an easy way to do this

Also see: http://www.redips.net/php/from-mysql-to-xml/ if you're planning on doing this with php (much simpler method)

Comment: Hello! This is my first question and, I must say, I´m amazed at how great this site is.
The workaround you provided is interesting, and can save lot of time if I have to take this road; it`s certainly not as straightforward as I was excepting! PHP would be easier, but I need complete log of changes, even those done directly to the DB and I`m not aware of any way to call a script from inside a trigger. It would be great to have this "log process" happening in the DB. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: glad you've found things helpful. I, too, was (and still am) amazed at the depth of knowledge some folks here have. If it needs to happen from within the db, then the first solution is the way to go -- even if it is a little awkward.

Comment: if this answers your question satisfactorily, could you click the check mark on the left to mark this as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

There is no exactly same clause, but you can easily emulate it using:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<id>', id, '</id>' SEPARATOR ''))
FROM    car
```