# SQL - Formatting XML response value

Tags: sql, sqlxml

I want to receive my response XML in following format...

```
<PersonDetails>
    <Name>Ajay</Name>
    <Age>29</Age>
    <ContactDetails>
        <ContactDetail>
            <ContactType>Mobile</ContactType>
            <ContactValue>9565649556</ContactValue>
        </ContactDetail>
        <ContactDetail>
            <ContactType>Email</ContactType>
            <ContactValue>ajay@yahoo.com</ContactValue>
        </ContactDetail>
    </ContactDetails>
</PersonDetails>
```

I have 2 different select statements here...

```
SELECT name, age FROM Person_Details
WHERE id = 12

SELECT Contact_Type, Contact_Value FROM Person_Contact_Details
Where id = 12
```

Any suggestions here...I tried with combinations of FOR XML EXPLICIT/PATH.

Comment: what's your DBMS? MSSQL? MySQL?
Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999513/what-is-the-equivalent-of-for-xml-auto-in-mysql-for-having-an-xml-string-that/999531#999531

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PATH`:

```
SELECT name AS Name
            , age AS Age
            , (SELECT Contact_Type AS ContactType
                , Contact_Value AS ContactValue
                FROM Person_Contact_Details c
                WHERE c.id = p.id
                FOR XML PATH('ContactDetail'), TYPE) AS ContactDetails
        FROM Person_Details p
        WHERE id = 12
        FOR XML PATH('PersonDetails')
```